# No se muestra Componente Vue en Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hace tiempo comence a trabajar con laravel y llego el momento de utilizar e implementar Vue el framework de TypeScript que utiliza, El problema es que no he podido hacer uso de los Componentes de Vue, he intentado de muchas formas y no logro hacer que el Componente se muestre en Pantalla.

A continuación el código que implemento en en mi proyecto(Menciono que no muestra ninguno error o bug, si no que solo no se muestra el componente a la hora de isntanciarlo.)

Versiones package.json

```js
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "argon-design-system-free": "^1.0.1"
    }
```

En mi registro de componentes app.json

```js
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i);
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default));

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('spinner', require('./components/Spinner.vue'));
/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
      components: {
        example,
  }
});
```

Componente(Cualquiera)

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Welcome.blade.php

```html
<div id="app"><ExampleComponent></ExampleComponent></div>
```

CÓDIGO COMPLETO DE MI VISTA

```html
@extends('layouts.app', ['class' => 'bg-default'])

@section('content')
<style media="screen">

        .carousel-control-next-icon {
          background-image : url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23ff0000' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M1.5 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")
          color: black;
        }
        .carousel-control-prev{
          color:back;
        }
        .carousel-control-next{
  
        }
        .pointer {cursor: pointer;}
  
        .carousel-fade {
      .carousel-inner {
          .item {
              transition-property: opacity;
          }
  
          .item,
          .active.left,
          .active.right {
              opacity: 0;
          }
  
          .active,
          .next.left,
          .prev.right {
              opacity: 1;
          }
  
          .next,
          .prev,
          .active.left,
          .active.right {
              left: 0;
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          }
      }
  
      .carousel-control {
          z-index: 2;
      }
  }
  
  
  
  html,
  body,
  .carousel,
  .carousel-inner,
  .carousel-inner .item {
      height: 100%;
  }
  
  .item:nth-child(1) {
      background: #74C390;
  }
  
  .item:nth-child(2) {
      background: #51BCE8;
  }
  
  .item:nth-child(3) {
      background: #E46653;
  }
      </style>

<h2 class="display-3 text-primary mb-6">Bienvenido</h2>

<div id="app"><example></example></div>


<div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4500">
        <h3 class="heading text-info mb-0">Productos recomendados</h3>
        <hr>
        <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto slide carousel-fade" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="card pointer mb-2" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">
                        <br>
                        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/walmart-labs/image/upload/w_960,dpr_1,f_auto,q_auto:eco/mg/images/product-images/img_large/00085369936013-2l.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body mb-1">
                          <h5 class="card-title text-default mb-1">Card title 1</h5>
                          <p class="card-text text-success mb-1">$50.00 </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="card pointer mb-2" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">
                        <br>
                        <img src="https://d2pa5gi5n2e1an.cloudfront.net/global/images/product/mobilephones/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A_L_1.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body text-default mb-1">
                          <h5 class="card-title mb-1">Card title 2</h5>
                          <p class="card-text text-success mb-1">$50.00 </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="card pointer" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">
                        <br>
                        <img src="https://d2pa5gi5n2e1an.cloudfront.net/global/images/product/mobilephones/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A_L_1.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body mb-1">
                          <h5 class="card-title text-default mb-1">Card title 3 </h5>
                          <p class="card-text text-success mb-1">$50.00 </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="card pointer" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">
                        <br>
                        <img src="https://d2pa5gi5n2e1an.cloudfront.net/global/images/product/mobilephones/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A_L_1.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body mb-1">
                          <h5 class="card-title text-default mb-1">Card title 4</h5>
                          <p class="card-text text-success mb-1">$50.00 </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="card pointer" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">
                        <br>
                        <img src="https://d2pa5gi5n2e1an.cloudfront.net/global/images/product/mobilephones/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A_L_1.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body mb-1">
                          <h5 class="card-title text-default mb-1">Card title 5</h5>
                          <p class="card-text text-success mb-1">$50.00 </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="card pointer" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">
                        <br>
                        <img src="https://d2pa5gi5n2e1an.cloudfront.net/global/images/product/mobilephones/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A_L_1.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body text-default mb-1">
                          <h5 class="card-title mb-1">Card title 6</h5>
                          <p class="card-text text-success mb-1">$50.00 </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                      <div class="card pointer" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">
                      <br>
                      <img src="https://d2pa5gi5n2e1an.cloudfront.net/global/images/product/mobilephones/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A_L_1.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body mb-1">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-default mb-1">Card title 7</h5>
                        <p class="card-text text-success mb-1">$50.00 </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                      <div class="card pointer" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">
                      <br>
                      <img src="https://d2pa5gi5n2e1an.cloudfront.net/global/images/product/mobilephones/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A_L_1.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body mb-1">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-default mb-1">Card title 8</h5>
                        <p class="card-text text-success mb-1">$50.00 </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                      <div class="card pointer" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">
                      <br>
                      <img src="https://d2pa5gi5n2e1an.cloudfront.net/global/images/product/mobilephones/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A_L_1.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body mb-1">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-default mb-1">Card title 9</h5>
                        <p class="card-text text-success mb-1">$50.00 </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <div class="card pointer" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">
                      <br>
                      <img src="https://d2pa5gi5n2e1an.cloudfront.net/global/images/product/mobilephones/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A_L_1.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body mb-1">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-default mb-1">Card title 10</h5>
                        <p class="card-text text-success mb-1">$50.00 </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <div class="card pointer" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">
                      <br>
                      <img src="https://d2pa5gi5n2e1an.cloudfront.net/global/images/product/mobilephones/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A_L_1.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body mb-1">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-default mb-1">Card title 11</h5>
                        <p class="card-text text-success mb-1">$50.00 </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <div class="card pointer" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">
                      <br>
                      <img src="https://d2pa5gi5n2e1an.cloudfront.net/global/images/product/mobilephones/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A/Xiaomi_Redmi_6A_L_1.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body mb-1">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-default mb-1">Card title 12</h5>
                        <p class="card-text text-success mb-1">$50.00 </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
             $('.carousel').carousel();
       });
      </script>



<script src="{{ asset('') }}/js/app.js"></script>
@endsection
```

El tema es que con ningun componente puedo ver los cambios incluso aun que ejecute: npm run development -- --watch
no se muestra el componente a implementar

Ojala alguien pueda decirme que es lo que sucede

Saludos a todos!

Comment: y en la vista donde tratas de mostrar los componentes, incluiste el llamado al archivo app.js?

Comment: aparte a tu registro del segundo componente le falta el acceso al método `default` checa aquí: https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/upgrade

Comment: como puedo importar el archivo app.js??

Comment: agrega el código completo de tu vista para así poder revisar si agregaste el llamado a `app.js` o no

Comment: Listo ojala puedas revisarlo saludos!

Comment: `<script src="{{ asset('') }}/js/app.js"></script>` es correcta esa URL? Si abrís la vista del código HTML desde tu navegador y hacés click en la URL que se genera en el `src`, carga el archivo `app.js`? Si reemplazás `<example></example>` por `<example-component></example-component>`?

Answer (score 1):

En `welcome.blade` estás llamando al componente como `ExampleComponent`. El nombre con el que se registra en `app.js` es `example-component`. Además, debes añadir:

```html
<link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Y:

```html
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

Si tu aplicación extiende de `app.blade.php`, entonces deberás colocarlo allí.

Answer (score 0):

Me acaba de pasar, casí que no doy con el chiste, cada vez que realicemos una modificación en Vue se debe ejecutar el comando

```
npm run dev
```

En consola, es como para refrescar y se tomen los cambios.

Answer (score 0):

es por que tienes que usar una etiqueta de HTML y colocar el id="app" de esta manera te mostrara el componente de Vue que estas llamando.

**Ejemplo**

```
<div id="app"> <example-component></example-component> </div>
```

Comment: ejmplo <div id="app">
   <example-component></example-component>
</div>